# SQL Server - Return rows based on user role

Tags: t-sql, ms-access, sql-server-2012, vba, ms-access-2013

We are developing an Access application with a SQL Server backend. We have a table that has records that belong to division A, B or C. The users also belong to role A, B or C. We want each user to see only their corresponding division records, as well as only certain columns.

I've thought of two ways, one making different queries for each role and then, based on the user's role, change the source object of the form. However I don't know if it is possible to retrieve it from SQL SERVER with VBA (all VBA documentation I've found so far is quite lacking).

The other solution I thought was to implement this on the server, however I don't know how a T-SQL query or view could fetch only the information needed based on the user's role

Any ideas?

PS: I can't use functions or stored procedures. For some reason the SQL Server we have been provided has them disabled and IT Ops won't enable them (Don't know the logic behind that).

Comment: You could use views -link these tables to your roles

Comment: Each record is in a one to many relationship with records from another table. Depending on the number of items in the second table, a process marks it as A, B or C through a field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it's been a while since I posted this but I'll post the solution I came up with in the end. VBA is not quite necessary in this case. It can be done perfectly with views.

To retrieve the users roles, (inner) join the table database_role_members twice with the database_principals one. Join by Id (from database_principals) on both fields. With this, you get a list of all roles and their corresponding users. To get the roles of the user querying the database simply add a where clause that checks that the user name corresponds with the function USER_NAME.

Then, don't give permission to those roles to access the table we want to restrict access to. Instead, make a view that fetches info from that table and add a where clause that looks up the value from a column against the query that retrieves the user roles.

With this you can make a link in access to the view and will allow you to see only the records that correspond to the user roles.

While this approach is easy, it doesn't allow for more complicated row level security. For a more powerful approach it might be useful to check the following link.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn765131.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could create the same tables with different schemas and assign user rights to different schemas. For example, instead of using dbo.Users you could have Accounting.Users and Warehouse.Users. Assign users in an accounting group to the Accouting schema. Or as suggested above those could be views within a schema that select data from underlying tables.

Comment: Even if I use schemas, I'd have the same problems when linking the tables from Access. I would need to change between tables depending on schema.